# Looking for a technical overview of jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, documentation, jquery-mobile

I am implementing a mobile presentation of a website using jQuery Mobile. The JQM site provides [a nice intro](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/docs/about/intro.html) which includes features, accessibility concerns, and supported devices.

From the technical standpoint, I understand all of the [events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/docs/api/events.html) and when they fire, however, I'm a little fuzzy on what is actually happening under the hood. I believe there is more to it than meets the eye. I have found that it integrates well with RESTful oriented frameworks such as Rails and ASP.NET MVC, but does not do well with ASP.NET Web Forms.

Can anyone provide a brief overview of how it works including how, when, and why these additional events occur? The life-cycle of a page loading and a page transition, for example, would be very helpful.

Comment: I think your best option is to view the source...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really good overview http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-jqmobile/

Comment: try this for a view on page lifecycle [link](http://bradbroulik.blogspot.in/2011/12/jquery-mobile-events-diagram.html)

Comment: @vinit your ibm link is not having the technical insight :(

Comment: @sij: The link you posted didn't existed when I tried to help..thanks though #lookattimestamp